# Angular 2, pipe test with observable has no transform access

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm writing the unit test for my pipe. The pipe uses a custom service to request api data. Following the outline here: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-testing-guide-a485b6cb1ef0 and a few other sources I put together:

```
describe('UserDataPipe', () => {

  let pipe;
  const userSvcMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['getUser']);

  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [UserDataPipe],
    providers: [
      { provide: UserService, useValue: userSvcMock }
    ]
  }));

  beforeEach(inject([UserService], p => {
    pipe = p;
  }));

  it('create an instance', () => {
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should return user display name (firstName lastName)', () => {
    console.log(pipe);
  });
});
```

However, `pipe` doesn't have access to the `transform` method I need to test against. It has access to the actual observable called in the `transform` method, `getUser`.

It was suggested I use this method but that gives the same result:

```
 let pipe;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const userService = jasmine.createSpyObj('UserService', ['getUser']);
    pipe = new UserDataPipe(userService);
  });
```

Pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'userData'
})
export class UserDataPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  transform(value: string, userProp?: any): any {
    let userData;
    return this.userService.getUser(value).pipe(
      map(res => {
        userData = res;
        if (!userProp) {
          return userData;
        } else {
          const prop = userProp === 'displayName' ? `${userData.firstName} ${userData.lastName}` : res[userProp];
          return prop;
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue `beforeEach(inject([UserService], p => {});`. At that point is not longer `UserDataPipe` with `transform()` and is now an instance of `UserService`. If you added a type like `let pipe: UserDataPipe`, the IDE would have warned you about this. That article is very old. You should really review the current documentation regarding [testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing) instead. That `inject` style really isn't used anymore.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I updated my question with a different approach that doesn't use `inject`

Comment: Can you please share the code to the pipe? If you implemented PipeTransform correctly then you should have access. Also can you clarify where in the test you are calling pipe.transform()?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Pipe code added. Calling in a simple `it()` at the moment. However, calling it returns an undefined. Console logging `pipe` returns an object that shows only the `getUser` function to be available.